# Filter list items by current user name or account in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

How to set a view filter with CurrentUser name or account?

I have a customer string colummn "manager" in each list item of sharepoint. I want to filter by current user information is equal to the value of "manager".

I want to make that the when current user is the "manager", he can view/edit the list items

I tried following scenarios,
 "manager" equals to [ME]
 "manager" equals to [Current User]

Please advice which exact text value should my colummn "manager" to be so it can fits [ME] or [Current User] in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: You can use [ME] for person and people field. Your manager field is string. For a string field you can not use [ME].

Comment: Thanks CIAODO. I also try to add CurrentUserFilter web part, but there are not related list found when select Connections under the webpart.

There is a WebFormItemsList in and CUrrentUserFilter Web part in current page, neither of their has available "connections".So this also blocked me. Please kindly advice if you have other solution.

Comment: I want to see whether current user name is same as that in "manager"(String value), if yes, he can see the item. NO, he can't see the item.

Comment: CurrentUserFilter Webpart uses as default the name like i:0#.w|domain\loginname